# OData V4 return updated entity on patch

Tags: http-headers, odata, patch

I know that I can set the header like this

```
headers: {
    'Prefer': 'return=representation'
}
```

But I would like to ask if it's possible to make it the default behaviour on my controller.

```
public IHttpActionResult Patch(int key, Delta<T> delta)
{
    Validate(delta.GetEntity());

    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        return BadRequest(ModelState);

    var entity = Repository.GetByKey(key);
    if (entity == null)
        return NotFound();

    if (!AuthenticationService.HasWriteAccess(CurentUser, entity))
        return Unauthorized();

    try
    {
        delta.Patch(entity);
        Repository.Save();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        return InternalServerError(e);
    }
    return Updated(entity);
}
```

Is there an attribute I can set or can I configure it in startup?

Answer (score 3):

Try this. Change your return to this.

```
var updatedODataResult = Updated(entity);
updatedODataResult.Request.Headers.Add("Prefer", "return=representation");

return updatedODataResult;
```

Comment: Is there also an option to select what part of the entity to return?
I only want the id and another property for instance, instead of the whole entity.